# Nginx cache parameters

Tags: nginx

The docs for nginx (https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/content-cache/content-caching/ and http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html) writes:

```
proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_nocache $arg_nocache$arg_comment;
proxy_no_cache $http_pragma $http_authorization;
```

What does each parameter with $ mean? I understand that $cookie_nocache means if a cookie: `no_cache=true` is set then nginx will not use the cache. But I can't seem to find the rest.